# Abstract function pointer doesn't work

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having this code for a GUI design for a mbed microcontroller:

This is my abstract class Widget.h with different subclasses like Button or Fader (not sure I can add variables this way in a abstract class but it compiles.

```
class Layout; //incomplete type

class Widget {    
    public:
        virtual void display(int x, int y) = 0; //pure virtual function for displaying the object
        virtual bool touchEvent(int x, int y)= 0;  //pure virtual function for checking if the touch does something for the widget
        void (*function)();
        Layout *layout;
};
```

Now I want to call the function pointer that I created

```
 if(currentWidget->function != NULL){
                    (currentWidget->function)(); 
 }
```

But the program stops here. I also want to change the activeLayout like this, but it also doesn't work.

```
if(currentWidget->layout != NULL){
                    Layout *templayout = currentWidget->layout;
                    activeLayout = templayout;
}
```

Am I this wrong in my approach in this? How could I fix it?

Comment: The first problem is because you're trying to treat a non-member function pointer as a member function pointer. Which is it supposed to be? There's nothing obviously wrong with the second; how exactly doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yoo should assign a `NULL` value to `function`, for example in the constructor, to make the test `if(currentWidget->layout != NULL)` meaningful, if you don't, function will point to some garbage, the test would pass and you will execute into garbage, causing a GPF in the best case.
Then, by a design point of view, why are you using a raw function pointer? Such things should be handled with polymorphism instead.

Comment: Ok, I understand the NULL value but what do you mean with the polymorphism? So skip the virtual functions? And why should I do that if it's that you mean?

Comment: yea you should avoid the function poinet, why don't use another virtual function instead?

Comment: I need the function pointer for example if you have a button it should do another function (but depends on how I setup my menu structure)